# How to create transparent pixels in html5 canvas that are not black in IE9

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to draw an image over another image in a canvas, and in the first image I am trying to remove the white pixels and make them transparent, but they are turning black.

This is the code I am using, but it's not looking correct. Does anyone see the problem?

```
function draw_graphic(canvas,context,lgo_type,gph_img,rib_type, hl_col,hl_txt,cp_col,cp_txt,in_col,in_txt,img_src,ban_bor) {
    // add the graphic image
    if (gph_img!="") {
        var img3 = new Image();
        img3.src = gph_img;

        img3.onload = function() {

            /*/////////////////////////////////////////*/
            var img6 = new Image();
            img6.src = remove_all_pixels(img3, 255, 255, 255);
            img6.onload = function() {
            /*/////////////////////////////////////////*/
                context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
                if (rib_type=="1" || rib_type=="3" || rib_type=="5") {
                    context.drawImage(this,0,0,143,105);
                } else {
                    context.drawImage(this,465,0,143,105);
                }
                context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';

                draw_logo(canvas,context,lgo_type,rib_type, hl_col,hl_txt,cp_col,cp_txt,in_col,in_txt,img_src,ban_bor);
            }
        };
    } else {
        draw_logo(canvas,context,lgo_type,rib_type, hl_col,hl_txt,cp_col,cp_txt,in_col,in_txt,img_src,ban_bor);
    }
}


function remove_all_pixels(image, r_val, g_val, b_val) {
    var canvas2 = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas2.getContext("2d");

    canvas2.width = image.width;
    canvas2.height = image.height;

    ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);

    var imgd = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas2.width, canvas2.height);
    var pix = imgd.data;

    for (var i = 0, n = pix.length; i < n; i += 4) {
        var r = pix[i],
            g = pix[i+1],
            b = pix[i+2];

        if(r == r_val && g == g_val && b == b_val){ 
            pix[i] = 0;
            pix[i+1] = 0;
            pix[i+2] = 0;
            pix[i+2] = 0;
        }
    }

    ctx.putImageData(imgd, 0, 0);
    return canvas2.toDataURL();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the offset of the last value from 2 to 3. Since `pix[i+3]` controls the alpha channel.

```
  if(r == r_val && g == g_val && b == b_val){ 
        pix[i] = 0;
        pix[i+1] = 0;
        pix[i+2] = 0;
        pix[i+3] = 0; // Change i+2, to i+3
    }
```

Sorry that was my fault from your last question. Was a typo in my code I provided in the answer, however the fiddle worked perfectly.

http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/BtbSM/